# Getting a Wemos D1 Mini to work with a M1 Mac

Tags: esp8266, mac-os

The Wemos D1 mini won't show up on the new M1 Mac. I know it's related to the drivers but I just can't find a viable solution to the problem. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: The CH340s have always been a problem with macs even before the M1. You could use a better USB UART interface instead of the built-in CH340, although I am not sure what makes actually support the M1. Maybe FT232 or PL210x would be a good bet.

Comment: program it on a different computer, and include OTA so you can update it from the mac.

Comment: I just found a solution for my TTGO board which also uses the CH340 chip, perhaps it'll work for you as well https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/85824/53182